# Best constant for Maier's theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Maier proved that, for fixed $\lambda>1,$
$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x+\log^\lambda x)-\pi(x)}{\log^{\lambda-1}x}>1
$$
and in particular
$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x+\log^\lambda x)-\pi(x)}{\log^{\lambda-1}x}>\frac{e^\gamma}{\lambda}
$$
which is for $\lambda<e^\gamma$ is sharper. Has this been improved? Are upper bounds known? Is there an effective bound for the $\liminf$?

Comment: Have you tried finding the review of Maier's paper on MathSciNet to see whether there are any later reviews that refer to it?

Comment: ... or the same on Google Scholar

Comment: Yes I tried MathSciNet (but not Google Scholar, maybe I'll try that later) -- but it's a heavily-cited paper and I might have missed something, or something new might have come up that isn't yet indexed.